# Building front before creating Docker image

Tags: java, reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and currently and I'm working on the dokernizing some apps.

Structure of project :

```
-PlayProject

-------app
----------controllers
----------models
----------views

-------ci
-------conf
-------project

-------public
----------css
----------js
----------img
----------fonts

-------sbt-cache
-------src
-------target

-------front
------------header (npm folder)
------------footer (npm folder)
-------Dockerfile
----*
```

The project is developed with PlayFramework (with sbt as a build tool) on Backend and Reactjs on front. The front is constritued from gtwo modules (header and footer).

On my dockerfile I need to run build the modules front (run 'npm run build' commands in both folders header and footer) to update the public folder before conternizing

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV HEADER front/header
ENV FOOTER front/footer
ENV PROJECT_HOME /usr/src
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.2.1

#install node
RUN  \
        curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash  && \
        # and install node
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install nodejs && \
        # confirm that it was successful
        node -v && \
        # npm installs automatically
        npm -v

WORKDIR $HEADER/

RUN  \
         echo $(ls -1 $HEADER/) && \
        npm cache clean && \
        npm i && \
        npm run build

WORKDIR $FOOTER/

RUN \
        echo $(ls -1 $FOOTER/) && \
        npm cache clean && \
        npm i && \
        npm run build


RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME/sbt $PROJECT_HOME/app

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/sbt

# Install curl
RUN \
       apt-get update && \
       apt-get -y install curl && \
       apt-get -y install vim

# Install sbt
RUN \
        curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
        dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
        rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get -y install sbt


COPY . $PROJECT_HOME/app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/app

EXPOSE 9000
```

The issue is that I cannot localize the front folders and run my npm commands. what do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not actually sending your local source to the Docker container, so there's nothing to build.

Try adding a line like `COPY . .` before you switch the WORKDIR.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set an absolute path to your first WORKDIR instruction :

> The WORKDIR instruction can be used multiple times in a Dockerfile. If a relative path is provided, it will be relative to the path of the previous WORKDIR instruction. For example:
>
> WORKDIR /a
>
> WORKDIR b
>
> WORKDIR c
>
> RUN pwd
>
> The output of the final pwd command in this Dockerfile would be /a/b/c.

[quoted from here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Maybe you want to replace your first WORKDIR like this :

```
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/$HEADER
COPY . .
# instead of just WORKDIR $HEADER/
```